# Access to the path 'Global\{xxx}_YYY-YYY:13552' is denied. Hangfire?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, hangfire

As the title says I encounter a "Access to the path" error in my MVC web application. The sites application pool is DefaultAppPool with identity Network Service. I have set Full Control to the Network Service user with no luck, I then tried to give Everyone full control but it still does not work. I'm running another application from the same folder (C:\Users\YYY\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects) and it works without a problem.

The file that fails contains the method that starts Hangfire. Could this have something to do with it?

I'm running Windows 10 Pro with IIS 10.0.

```
public void Start()
{
    lock (_lockObject)
    {
        if (_started) return;
        _started = true;

        HostingEnvironment.RegisterObject(this);

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
            .UseSqlServerStorage("connection string");
            // Specify other options here
        _backgroundJobServer = new BackgroundJobServer();
    }
}
```

http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/deployment-to-production/making-aspnet-app-always-running.html

Current permissions for

> C:\Users\YYY\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Project

[image: Security settings]

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Access to the path
>   'Global{4deecd4f-19f6-426b-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}_YYY-YYY:13552' is
>   denied.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the
>   path
>   'Global{4deecd4f-19f6-426b-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}_YYY-YYY:13552' is
>   denied.
>
> ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider
>   granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request
>   identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically
>   {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6 and IIS 7, and
>   the configured application pool identity on IIS 7.5) that is used if
>   the application is not impersonating. If the application is
>   impersonating via , the identity will be
>   the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated
>   request user.
>
> To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in File
>   Explorer, choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click "Add"
>   to add the appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET account,
>   and check the boxes for the desired access.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 36:                 _backgroundJobServer = new BackgroundJobServer();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, I had two websites with Hangfire running on the same application pool. When I created a new application pool for each website everything started working.

It seems as both instances of Hangfire when running on the same application pool tried to communicate through the same port and because of this the application that got started first was the only one to be working. The reason they were on the same application pool to start with was pure laziness, I only created a virtual directory from within Visual Studio at my local IIS to run the project.

[image]